# Bag with coloured balls, draw pairs, not all pairs allowed

Tags: probability

I have a bag which contains $n_1$ white balls, $n_2$ black balls and $n_3$ red balls. The total is $n=n_1+n_2+n_3$.

I pick randomly two balls. If none of this pair is red I put both balls back to the bag, because only WR, BR, and RR pairs are valid.

I continue picking valid pairs of balls until all red balls are drawn from the bag. Or until only one ball (whichever color) is in the bag.

There are many possibilities, depending on how many WR, BR, RR pairs are picked.

My question is: How do I calculate the probability of every possibility? Which is the most likely?

Another approach is: How many RR, RB, RW pairs is the most likely?

For example, let's say $10$ red, $3$ black, $2$ white. And the arrangements: RR,RR,RR,RB,RB,RW,RW (put it ordered for easy reading, the real order doesn't matter at all).
Another arrangement can be RR,RR,RR,RR,RR (no W/B picked). Which are the probabilities of these two cases?

Is 4 RR, 2 RB, 2 RW the most likely event?

Comment: We can calculate the probability of any specific pair of colors being chosen. That is not so bad. But it seems you are asking for the probability the $x$ pair drawings will suffice to empty the bag and/or remove all red balls. Is that correct?

Comment: @TheCount I'm asking about the probability of any arrangement. I showed two examples, two probabilities needed. I don't care about a specific pair, but about all of them after all drawns.

Comment: So for each $(r,b,w)$ you want the probability that $r$ red balls, $b$ black balls, and $w$ white balls have been removed from the bag at the end.  Is that correct?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm interested in counting pairs, but probably of (r,b,w) seems good (if not the same with other words)

Comment: It seems to me you have to do it with a computer program, but a recursive function should be straightforward to program.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I can do a computer program. I hoped a mathematical approach, which I'm not skilled enough.